# Difference between two TensorFlow methods for mixed precision

Tags: precision, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm adding Automatic Mixed Precision to a TensorFlow 2 model. What's the interaction between

`tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy('mixed_float16')` and `tf.config.optimizer.set_experimental_options({"auto_mixed_precision": True})` ?

The former is documented at the [Keras mixed precision guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision), and the latter doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere except the [API docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/optimizer/set_experimental_options). Using the experimental options call seems to work, while setting the policy gives me datatype mismatches in my model.

I'm using `GradientTape`, so the simplistic solutions relating to `model.fit()` don't apply to me. Any insight on the similarities, differences, and interactions between these two functions?